# Where did the "All Users" folder from XP go in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

I'd like to place some files in a folder that shows up on all user's desktop on a machine.  What do I need to know about the differences between Win7 and XP to do this?  Is this still possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`C:\Users\Public\` is the equivalent to `All Users` in Win 7

`Desktop` is the folder you want (it is labelled `Public Desktop`) and it is hidden so you will need to set `Show hidden files, folders, and drives`

The full path is `C:\Users\Public\Desktop` (if your system drive is C:)

Comment: Exactly like you said - Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Start menu is `%systemdrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\`

Answer (score 4):

I know this has already been answered, and the answer is correct for most systems. However, sometimes the public folder does get moved elsewhere, particularly if you install Windows to a drive other than C:. You can use `%allusersprofile%` to always go to wherever the directory is installed on the given system.

Comment: Good point.  Noted.

Comment: That environment variable is not the same - on Windows 7 it is `C:\ProgramData`, but the public profile is `C:\Users\Public`.

Comment: @KevinBrock: You're right that `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` points to a different directory, but the default junctions installed for backwards compatibility take you to the correct directory for most common subdirs.  For example `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Desktop` is a junction to `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`.  See [this stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3414264/277307) for a good link on these junctions.  Use `dir /AL %ALLUSERSPROFILE%` to view the junctions under `C:\ProgramData`.  (You can also use the `%PUBLIC%` env var to refer to the public user dir directly.)

Answer (score 0):

It still exists - you'll now find as `%SYSTEMDRIVE%/Users/Public/`.